# How was this unmount animation achieved by DarcStudio?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been trying to rebuild the animation of the darcstudio website on their work index page that happens when redirecting to a project detail page. How are they doing it? Do they clone the index page onto the detail page and then unmount it?

Screen capture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX4gL.jpg